# Why did the validation accuracy improved dramatically when I continued retraining again?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

***Issue: My validation accuracy made a large improvement when training the model the 2nd time around. Want to know the reason why, and if possible, replication.***

I saved my models output as ".h5" format.

My validation accuracy hovered around "**~0.47**" for the last few hundred epochs the first round I trained the model. Ending on accuracy "**0.6709**".

(*Final Training Results - 1st Training*)
[image]

Here is my model's layers. I used Keras-Tuner to extract the best model architecture (i.e. for validation accuracy)

[image]

I am using a batch size of "512" out of "~750,000" training examples: 1/1473.

I continued training on the model (by using Keras load models) and it began training at "**0.5564**". However the validation accuracy jumped all the way to "**0.6560**". A nearly 20% improvement. Then it begin trending downwards. Side note - reshuffling is part of the preprocessing of the data set before training:

(*Second Training*)
[image]

So I have a few questions:

1. Why did the validation accuracy jumped so high/when I reloaded the model for retraining - but when training normally through epochs it never broke past "**0.48**"?
2. Why when I retrain the model, does it drops so significantly downwards from training accuracy "**0.6709** to "**0.5564**"? (I was told it was due to batch sized training but at 512/750,000, it should be a relatively minor drop? Unless its the data reshuffling...)

Answer (score 0):

I reshuffled some of the validation data into the training data. That is the reason for the jump.

Comment: yes. Shuffling the data always gets you a better performance. It reduces a bit the chances of the NN to memorise the data.